# Multiple SSL certificates in JMeter

Tags: ssl, jmeter

I would like to use multiple SSL certificates for my thread group which simulates 100 users. SSL Manager allows me to specify one certificate which Jmeter would use to make SSL connection for all 100 users, Is it possible to use multiple certificates?  The reason for multiple certificates is that each has different roles/authorization.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was implementeded in new version 2.6.
The description of this enhancement at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52033.

Answer (score 0):

Having not tried this before, I *believe* you'll need to setup different threadgroups for each role, and give each thread group a different SSL Manager.